# list.map can take a string in scala

Tags: scala, collections

Is str somehow implicitly converted to str.charAt, so the map function works?

```
val str = "abcdefghij"
println(List.range(0, 10).map(str));
```

Answer (score 5):

since `str` is Seq of character, `.map` on `str` will call given index.

eg.

```
scala> List.range(0, 10).map(str)
res0: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)

// or .apply
scala> List.range(0, 10).map(str.apply)
res7: List[Char] = List(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

And `str(index)` gives the value for index, see [`StringOps#apply(index: Int): Char`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html)

```
scala> "my string"(4)
res5: Char = t
```

Other `Array` and `Seq` example,

```
scala> val array = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
array: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> List.range(0, 4).map(array)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val list = Seq(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
list: Seq[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

scala> List.range(0, 4).map(list)
res3: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

Comment: For the string case, is it because of the apply function? Such that actually it is doing: `.map(x => "abc"(x))`

Comment: True, same with all Sequences. `StringOps#apply` or `LinearSeqOptimized#apply`.